# Can't share images using via Pinterest in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I got a problem when sharing the images on Pinterest. I got a response as pinned failed. How to share the images by using in pinterest?

Here is my code:

I installed pods but I can't pinned images.

```
[PDKPin pinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://about.pinterest.com/sites/about/files/logo.jpg"] link:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.pinterest.com"]
          suggestedBoardName:@"" note:@"The Pinterest Logo" withSuccess:^
      {
          // weakSelf.resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"successfully pinned pin"];
      }
                  andFailure:^(NSError *error)
      {
          //weakSelf.resultLabel.text = @"pin it failed";
          NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
          
      }];
```

I got the response

```
2018-03-22 16:25:25.591507+0530 DirectoryApp[5548:930657] pin it failed
2018-03-22 16:25:25.591605+0530 DirectoryApp[5548:930657] Error Domain=PDKPin Code=2 "(null)"
```

Comment: Can you post the debugger out put of the `NSLog` of the error?

Comment: it navigate to the pintrest there i can create the bord but image scant post

Comment: i wont get any response

Comment: Error Domain=PDKPin Code=2 "(null)"

Comment: 2018-03-22 16:25:25.591507+0530 DirectoryApp[5548:930657] pin it failed
2018-03-22 16:25:25.591605+0530 DirectoryApp[5548:930657] Error Domain=PDKPin Code=2 "(null)"